# How to convert a "Polygon" to a "GeometryCollection" type in PostGIS

Tags: postgis, sql

With this simplified example (In reality I have thousands of points):

```
CREATE TABLE test
(
  geog geometry(GeometryCollection)
);

INSERT INTO test VALUES (ST_ConcaveHull('MULTIPOINT(-109 29, -110 28, 30 10, -109 29)',0.99));
```

I get the following error:

```
ERROR: Geometry type (Polygon) does not match column type (GeometryCollection)
```

How can I convert the `Polygon` type to a `GeometryCollection` type?

[`ST_Multi`](http://www.postgis.org/docs/ST_Multi.html) and [`ST_Collect`](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Collect.html) only convert to `MultiPolygon` , not `GeometryCollection`.

Comment: Can you explain why you want to set geog to type GeometryCollection ?

Comment: If you want a generic "can hold anything" geometry column, just omit the type modifier entirely. CREATE TABLE test (geom geometry)

Comment: Indeed, it works without defining `(GeometryCollection)`, I didn't know it was possible. What is the purpose of defining the type then? Some `CONSTRAINT` equivalent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can cast to GEOMETRYCOLLECTION using ST_ForceCollection http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Force_Collection.html

However, as suggested by Paul Ramsey, if you don't care about the type, you'd better drop the geometry type constraint from your geometry column.