# How do I cast an empty GeometryCollection to an empty typed geometry in PostGIS

Tags: postgis, geometrycollection

As a workaround to an obscure issue, I need to do exactly the opposite as describe here in order to harmonize my data set: [How to convert a "Polygon" to a "GeometryCollection" type in PostGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/225932/how-to-convert-a-polygon-to-a-geometrycollection-type-in-postgis) but with the tiny difference that my geometry collections are actually empty (`ST_IsEmpty()` returns `true`). (they are the result of an actual 3D intersection which sometimes gives empty geometry collections... I need to figure out why.)

So, to make it clear: how do I cast -- if possible -- an empty `ST_GeometryCollection` object to en empty *typed* geometry, i.e. either a point, line or polygon (or their corresponding multi parts, which should only be a matter of applying `ST_Multi()` on their single part versions)?

My final problem is this error message because I'm using a CTE to INSERT field in an existing table:

```
Geometry type (LineString) does not match column type (MultiLineString)
```

Version info:

```
PostgreSQL 14.1 (Debian 14.1-1.pgdg110+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu,
    compiled by gcc (Debian 10.2.1-6) 10.2.1 20210110, 64-bit

POSTGIS="3.1.4 ded6c34"
    [EXTENSION]
        PGSQL="140"
        GEOS="3.9.0-CAPI-1.16.2"
        SFCGAL="1.3.8"
        PROJ="7.2.1"
        LIBXML="2.9.10"
        LIBJSON="0.15"
        LIBPROTOBUF="1.3.3"
        WAGYU="0.5.0 (Internal)"
        TOPOLOGY
```

Comment: There is some historical discussion in https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/106932/empty-geometries-in-geometrycollection and https://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/wiki/DevWikiEmptyGeometry. I know that OpenJUMP supports all kind of empty geometries and it can also make conversions between different nothings but that does not help you. Maybe you could go via WKT presentation and edit whatever you have in front of EMPTY into  whatever you want to have there.

Comment: Given that a) PostGIS doesn't fully implement empty types throughout its functionality and b) (unnecessarily) storing them requires a specific test to not include them in further operations, consider to simply `NULL`ify  them instead (e.g. `CASE WHEN ST_IsEmpty(geom) THEN NULL ELSE geom END`. Either way, keeping them is likely unwanted, so better try to avoid them in the first place.

Comment: It's not a cast, but you can create a new empty geom if the collection is empty `select st_asText('MULTILINESTRING EMPTY'::geometry);` .. but I agree, I would store `Null` or not store at all

Comment: As to why you're getting empty collections - if you're not snapping your geometry or snapping to a grid, you're comparing floats.  They aren't going to match up exactly like you would expect unless you snap them.  Without snapping, you'll get infinitesimally small differences in the coordinates, and you wont get as many exact matches as you would expect for functions like st_intersects and st_intersection, which expect the coordinate(s) to match.  Another issue is that you may be running `st_intersection` on non-intersecting lines, which will return an empty collection.

Comment: You could cast your nulls to the desired type as well `null::geometry(multilinestring,4326)`